# Cannot install Tivion from PPA

Tags: updates, update-manager

The message I get is:

```
Check your Internet connection.
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shakaran/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shakaran/ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Comment: As others have pointed out, this PPA is very old and doesn't offer packages for the last versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I seems that this particular location you want to fetch doesn't exist.

Check by browsing the dists folder: http://ppa.launchpad.net/shakaran/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

There is no directory named "quantal".

Answer (score 1):

Don't just copy and paste stuff. [The PPA](https://launchpad.net/~shakaran/+archive/ppa) was last updated on 2010-03-30 and only includes packages up to 10.04 (lucid). The developer may probably have abandoned the project, the software might still work on newer releases though, but I haven't found information on the blog linked in the PPA's description.

Regarding the quality of your question: Information on what you were trying to do (installing tivion I guess), what Ubuntu release you are using as well as clarification that your Internet connection is working fine is completely missing in your question. Your question lacks human interaction at all. If you don't care about your issue, why should volunteers like us do?

Please put plain error messages regarding Ubuntu into your favored Internet search engine. If that doesn't help, kindly ask questions to humans here.